# queryselectorAll usage

Tags: javascript

I am currently upating my organisations custom JS library and one thing I am looking to introduce is querySelectorAll.

Looking at compatibility it will run in modern browser and for older browsers I will use feature detection:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll) {
            var nodes = context.querySelectorAll(queryValue);
} else {
    var nodes = context.getElementsByTagName(queryValue);
}
```

Are there any considerations that I should be aware of when using this method or is it good for production?

All opinions valued

Comment: As long as you are sure that `queryValue` only contains a tag name, it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Main difference between the two is that:

```
getElementsByTagName
```

...will return a *"live list"*, and

```
querySelectorAll
```

...will not.

Since this seems to be only for selection by tag, I'd probably ditch the `qsa`, so you can have the live list if needed. I've got a feeling that `qsa` may be slower in some browsers as well, but haven't tested it.

---

**EDIT:**

[This test](http://jsperf.com/els-by-tag-name-vs-queryselectorall) shows a big performance difference between the two in Chrome 13.

Comment: yes there is a big performance gain from qsa, although this example just looks for a tag the roll out will include tag and classname e.g. div.className. The fall back being a getElementsByTagName with a loop to find if the element has a particular classname (which would produce an even bigger performance gain). 

Was just checking that it was 'safe' to implement which it appears to be.

Comment: @user: In that case, you probably don't care about the "live list" aspect, and as such, you should be fine.