# Selecting Children HTML elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>

 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>

 <section>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="previous-page.html">Previous</a></li>
       <li><a href="next-page.html">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
 </section>

</body>
```

I want to select what is inside the `<li>` tags that are in the `<nav>` element and put them in a list, but not include the `<li>` tags that are in `<section>`.

I've tried this code, but it selects all the list elements on the entire page:

```
let list = document.selectElementsByTagName('li')
```

I can only use vanilla  JS, not jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [queryselectorAll usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584333/queryselectorall-usage)

Comment: `selectElementsByTagName` is not valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually `getElementsByTagName`...
But you could use `.querySelectorAll()` like:

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll('nav li')
```

Example:

```js
let list  = document.querySelectorAll('nav li');
let list2 = document.querySelector('section ul'); // Use rather some ID man 

Array.from(list).forEach( (el) => list2.append(el.cloneNode(true)) );
```

```css
section {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="previous-page.html">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="next-page.html">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to use vanilla JavaScript. But with jQuery you could do the same with less code:

```
let list = $('nav li');
```

Comment: less code? the whole jQuery library is not necessarily less code :) just less typing ;)